# Change a parameter in SharedParameter Revit API C#

Tags: c#, revit-api

Please tell me how to change the `ShouldHideWhenNoValue` parameter in the `SharedParameter` loaded in the project.

```cs
var collector = new FilteredElementCollector(doc)
    .OfClass(typeof(SharedParameterElement))
    .WhereElementIsNotElementType()
    .Cast<SharedParameterElement>()
    .FirstOrDefault(gp => gp.GuidValue.Equals(ADSK.Tolshina_Stenki));
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you would like to achieve. You can create a new shared parameter, but you cannot change an existing non-shared parameter into a shared one. Furthermore, the Revit API only supports the same functionality as the user interface, so it will help to research how to achieve the desired result in the UI, and what best practices to follow in doing so. I hope this helps, even without understanding your task.

Comment: Hi @JeremyTammik! Sorry for my English, I am from Ukraine and I translate my question with translator. I wanted to use ClearValue Method for Shared parameters, but it works when those have their HideWhenNoValue property set to true. I wanted to know if there is any way to change this property using Revit Api or if it can only be changed in the Shared parameters text file.

Answer (score 1):

Just to update this tread to 2023. One can use the new Parameters Service on the cloud and its API to change the parameters. You can [read about this new service for Revit in this article](https://goto.archi/blog/post/how-to-use-the-autodesk-parameter-service-in-revit).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your further explanation in your comment. I was previously unaware of this functionality. Prompted by your explanation, I found it in the [What's New in the Revit 2020 API](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/04/whats-new-in-the-revit-2020-api.html) section on [Hiding empty parameters](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/04/whats-new-in-the-revit-2020-api.html#4.2.8.2):

> The new property
>
> - ExternalDefinition.HideWhenNoValue
>
> Indicates if the shared parameter should be hidden from the property palette and Element.GetOrderedParameters() when it has no value.
>
> Similar functionality has been added to other classes:
>
> - ExternalDefinitionCreationOptions.HideWhenNoValue
> - SharedParameterElement.ShouldHideWhenNoValue()
>
> The new method:
>
> - Parameter.ClearValue()
>
> can reset the value of a shared parameter which has the HideWhenNoValue flag set back to a cleared state. (This method is not applicable to clear the value of any other parameter type).